# How to populate a google sheet template with response data from a google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

In the past I used an add-on that allowed me to generate a google sheet corresponding to a google form response. However, the add-on that I was using has a limit to the number of documents that can be created, and I was hoping to find an alternative.

Is there another way to take each response I receive in the google form and then generate a google sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can generate a Google Sheet with the Google Form's responses by clicking on `View Responses in Sheets`  button while on the Responses tab:

[image]

This should generate a sheet like this:

[image]

You can also configure this behavior on this page:

[Choose where to save form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686)